# Не устанавливается MySQL 5.7 на ubuntu 14

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить MySQL сервер версии 5.7, но в репозитории он 5.5 . Поэтому скачал deb файл отсюда:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

И выполнил dpkg -i , чтобы после установить сам mysql через apt-get install . Но после отправки этой команды:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

процесс зависает со следующим логом:

```
(Reading database ... 134111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) over (0.8.10-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
```

Останавливается только через ctrl+c . Как исправить? Или есть другой способ установить именно эту версию mysql?

Comment: А система обновлена до актуального состояния?

Answer (score 0):

На Ubuntu 14.04 идет версия MySQL 5.5 в дефолтных репозиториях. Для того чтобы установить версию 5.7, необходимо добавить репозиторий:
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server